# How to get the index value in ngfor while using modal popup?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

[image: Normal View]
[image: With Modal PopUp]

While clicking remove button, I opened the small popup for confirmation to delete the file.In popup I have a delete button, while user clicks the delete button, I passing the document id and index value.

Problem is, while clicking 3rd or any index, it takes the index 0 and 0th index document id.

**Html:**

```
<ng-template #tmplt>
    <tr *ngFor="let kbase of Colum; let i =index">
        <td *ngIf="kbase.DocumentDetails!=null">{{kbase.DocumentDetails.DocName}}</td>
        <td *ngIf="kbase.DocumentDetails==null"></td>
        <td>{{kbase.ModifiedBy}}</td>
        <td>{{kbase.ModifiedDate}}</td>
        <td>
            <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                <select name="select" class="form-control" (change)="status()" [(ngModel)]="kbase.IsStatus">
                    <option value="true">Active</option>
                    <option value="false">In Active</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <app-file-upload [documentModel]="kbase.DocumentDetails" [isDeleteRequired]="true" [isMultipleFile]="true" [model]="kbase" (emitterFile)="fileSelect($event,i)"></app-file-upload>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">Remove</button>
            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Delete</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            Are You Sure,You Want To Delete This Row?
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="Delete(i,kbase.DocumentDetails.Id)">Delete</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
```

**TS File:**
My Method:

```
Delete(index: number, id: number) {
        this.savestatus = false;
        if (index != -1) {
            this.Colum.splice(index, 1);
            if (id != 0) {
                this._knowledgebaseService.Delete(id).subscribe(x => {
                    if (x.Success)
                        this.deletemessage = true;
                    this.result = x; 
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: how are we opening the `modal`

Comment: This is wrong way to use modal popup in for loop, you have to just remove it from For loop and put outside it and then try to open popup and pass required parameter. In your current way it render same HTML for popup in DOM for each loop item

Comment: @SandipPatel ok, if I put the modal popup outside of the loop, how to pass the current index value and document Id?